# Linq - Select record from database by id

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I'm trying to get a record from the database with an id I specified. However I'm having difficulties creating the correct Linq query.
First off this is two of the things I've tried, but which don't seem to work.

```
var query_result = from d in db.Departments
                   where d.id == id
                   select d;
```

Here I try to select the department which follows my given id. However in my `Department` class the `id` attribute is private. Which I would like to keep that way, in compliance with normal OOP.

Before that I tried doing this:

```
var query_result = from d in db.Departments
                   where d.getId() == id
                   select d;
```

In this case I'm using the getter for the id, but that gives me the following error:

> Method 'Int32 getId()' has no supported translation to SQL.

I've tried looking around but I can't seem to find a conclusive answer for something that should be, in my opinion, very simple. I do see a lot of examples access the class attributes directly, but that would mean making them public. Unless I'm missing something I wouldn't really want to go that way.

I'm not very experienced in Linq (or c# for that matter). Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why is the Id private?  If you need the id, I can't fathom a reason why it would be private.  It literally identifies the record after all.

Comment: make getter public and setter private, instead

Comment: Usually you would just use the getter/setter for the id if you needed it. That way you can't change the id in a way that it isn't supposed to. Surely there's got to be to a way to keep the id private and somehow use a getter for this?

Comment: May be try to cast (int)d.getId()?Not sure though,guess it will not make difference.

Comment: `public int Id {get; private set;}`

Comment: @restless No that doesn't work, I think linq doesn't accept (int32) methods.

Comment: @Roar thanks I guess that works, still feels kind of weird to me though...

Comment: @Roar Just for fun; what would I do if I still wanted to use a (specific, defined by me) setter though? That wouldn't work?

Comment: @Bono u can set id by setId() method and if u want it in inherited class make it protected

Comment: Hm, I guess C# is different in that aspect than other languages (that it's still only settable through that method) I know. Thanks

Comment: @Bono You have discovered the concept of the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_impedance_mismatch.  You are trying to combine the object-oriented practice of encapsulation, with a database.  You can't hide the fact that there is an Id while simultaneously using it to query the database.  If you really really don't want the caller to know about the ID, you would need to generate a separate business layer and database layer, such that only the database layer sees the Id and the business layer does not.

Comment: Your `Department` object is an `entity` not a `business object`, it's as if you are trying to do that query in sql without the Id column being present.

Comment: @MobyDisk Thanks that helps a lot. Certainly not something I've encountered before :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Entity Framework, then you can't declare either the `get` or `set` as `private`, or else Entity Framework won't be able to access it either.

This is what you're looking for to ensure that the outside code is unable to set the IDs:

```
public int Id { get; protected internal set; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your current query is returning a list. Sounds like you need a single record? For that, use this:

```
var recordDesired = db.Departments.FirstOrDefault(d => d.id == id);
```

Assuming 'id' is an int defined somewhere, and the 'id' property is also int. Are you using entity framework by any chance? If so, I believe the 'id' property needs to have both a public getter and a public setter. I hear you on not exposing the ID to your end client application. One option would involving using DTO's (data transfer objects) to translate all the goodness that the database spews out and wrapping it in a simple class that only exposes the properties your end application cares about.